# Restart GNOME without restarting Xorg?

Tags: xorg, gnome

sometimes happens that some applications crash and make Gnome desktop unstable for example the upper bar vanishes. by restarting X ctrl+shift+backspace i can reset it. but is there a way just to re enable the bar or Gnome entirely?

Comment: Which version of GNOME are you using 2 or 3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to restart Gnome with

```
 gnome-shell --replace
```

From the manual:

```
DESCRIPTION
   GNOME Shell provides core user interface functions for the GNOME 3 desktop,
   like switching to windows and launching  applications.  GNOME  Shell  takes
   advantage  of  the  capabilities of modern graphics hardware and introduces
   innovative user interface concepts to provide  a  visually  attractive  and
   easy to use experience.

OPTIONS
   --replace
          Replace the running window manager
```

Comment: This works if you can still use a shell from the GUI. If you can't see my answer where I do it from another shell.

Answer (score 4):

You can press Alt-F2 (IIRC) to get a window where you can type a command. In addition to regular commands, GNOME Shell supports a couple of custom commands to control the behavior of the desktop environment. In this case, you want `restart`, which restarts the Shell, not the computer.

If it's crashed too much for that to work, use [terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91412/29146).

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR, if you cannot do it from the GUI just login as the same user (text console, ssh, etc) and type:

```
eval "$(while read -d $'\0' line; do printf 'export %q\n' "$line"; done </proc/$(pgrep -fu$USER gnome-session-binary)/environ)"
gnome-shell --replace >.xsession-errors 2>&1 &
```

I do it often from a text console. You can switch to other consoles using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F**n**</kbd> where **n** is a free console number, usually starting from <kbd>F3</kbd> as <kbd>F1</kbd> is the login screen and <kbd>F2</kbd> is the first session.

It obviously won't work with *Wayland* since gnome-shell restarts are just not supported on it.

---

Detailed answer:

The trick is to replicate the environment required by *gnome-shell* - I haven't verified exactly what is needed but at the very least you need `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` so *gnome-shell* can connect to the *X server*, and then a few additional ones are very likely required by *gnome-shell* and its extensions.

The process tree should look a bit like this:

```
      |            |-gdm-session-wor(6444)-+-gdm-x-session(6464)-+-Xorg(6466)-+-{InputThread}(6472)
      |            |                       |                     |            `-{radeon_cs:0}(6467)
      |            |                       |                     |-gnome-session-b(6475)-+-evolution-alarm(6712)-+-{dconf worker}(6789)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |            |                       |                     `-{gmain}(6465)
      |            |                       |-{gdbus}(6446)
      |            |                       `-{gmain}(6445)
```

In this example *gnome-session-binary* (pid 6475) is the parent of all gnome session processes, so this is what I use to get the environment. If we used `gnome-shell` directly we'd see a lot more variables set by gnome-shell itself for its subprocesses.

I use `pgrep` to return the *pid* of that process for the current user only (there should always be only one pid even with multiple users logged in; if you have managed to log on twice something went terribly wrong).

Then I read that task's `environ` file from `/proc/<PID>/` (null-separated list of environment variables), and prepend all lines with `export`. Those commands are then fed back to my shell through `eval`.

At this point I can run `gnome-shell --replace` like if I was doing it from the GUI session. If you plan on keeping that shell open you will likely want to redirect *STDOUT* and *STDERR* somewhere too; you can send it to `/dev/null` but I like to keep it around just in case (`.xsession-errors` is the legacy file X used to throw all GUI output to; on modern systems I believe *systemd* or *journald* capture all output and logs it instead).

Comment: This looks very promising. Have made a script for it, and for the first time in forever I'm actually waiting for GNOME to freeze lol. https://termbin.com/1bid

Answer (score 0):

You can restart gnome using as root:

```
services gdm restart
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Does it not work correctly?

Comment: This working correctly